# Difference in seismic analysis of RCC structure and an equipment

Tags: civil-engineering

I am a chemistry/metallurgy major and working on qualification of mechanical components (pressure vessels, closed leak tight enclosures, cells at high temperature etc.) and this is my first question in this stack exchange.

I wish to know if ETABS/STAAD Pro/SAP 2000, which are conventional FE softwares for seismic analysis of multi-storey buildings, heritage buildings, can be used for seismic qualification of a leak tight closed enclosure (ASME Section III, Div I code) inside which there is a mini-crane and the bottom of the enclosure has a small welded vessel.

I am quite sure that ANSYS would be a better tool to carry out seismic analysis of such mechanical components. I wish to know if building analysis softwares can be used for analysis of such components. I did not get a very convincing answer elsewhere.

Comment: I do not understand the connection with buildings. We did integrity checks of pressure vessels using sound detection ( crack extension and leaks).  The only calculations were triangulation to locate the  source. Also it was necessary to filter out extraneous sounds like pumps or compressors.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are interested in the interaction of the component and the building, you can model the component in accordance with the building code to generate the force envelope at their interface/connections.

No, if your interest is focused on the component equipment, the above analysis wouldn't offer meaningful mechanical responses. Instead, you should model the component independently and apply the results from the above analysis as the external applied driven forces.